# How to change data in XML/XLST?

Tags: xml, xslt

how can I convert XML file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file123.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
    <ReportBody>
      <Document
        Title="Report: TESTOWY FIXEDHOL">
        <Chapter
        Tag="0"
        Name="TEST_KAL1_I0"
        Label=""
        Dimension="1">
          <TableDef>
        <ColLabel>
          <D>Type</D>
          <D>Month</D>
          <D>Day</D>
          <D>WeekDay</D>
        </ColLabel>
          </TableDef>
          <Bloc
        Tag="1"
        Level="1"
        Label="">
        <DataRow Total="false">
          <D>FLOAT</D>
          <D>May</D>
          <D>12</D>
          <D>Thurday</D>
        </DataRow>
          </Bloc>
        </Chapter>
      </Document>
    </ReportBody>
```

so as to achieve like this (of course this is a shorter example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document UploadDate="20111021" ClientCode="AKK" Version="0">
    <HolidayRules>
        <HolidayRule>
            <Type>FIXED</Type>
            <Month>August</Month>
            <Day>2.0</Day>
            <WeekDay>Friday</WeekDay>
        </HolidayRule>  
    </HolidayRules>
</UploadDocument>
```

I know that probably I have to use XSLT but how can I do it ? Could you give me example of code to do it ?

Probabli it can be the solution, but how to use it? what does it mean test="position()=2"? and so on ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <UploadDocument>
      <xsl:for-each select="2KALROBOCZE/2VH">
        <Schedule>
          <xsl:for-each select="D">
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <Action>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </Action>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
              <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </Name>
              <Description>&#160;</Description>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 3">
              <DateSchedules>
                <DateSchedule>
                  <Date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </Date>
                </DateSchedule>
              </DateSchedules>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </DateSchedule>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </UploadDocument>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What have you done till, share your code which can help us to understand where are you getting stuck. And please try to use real scenarioes.

Comment: I added my code of xslt

Comment: Do note that your stylesheet has nothing in common with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This simple stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key  name="ColLabel-D-by-positionn" 
            match="ColLabel/D" 
            use="count(preceding-sibling::D) + 1"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document UploadDate="20111021" ClientCode="AKK" Version="0">
        <HolidayRules>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </HolidayRules>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DataRow">
        <HolidayRule>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </HolidayRule>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DataRow/D">
        <xsl:element name="{key('ColLabel-D-by-positionn', position())}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>    
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Document UploadDate="20111021" ClientCode="AKK" Version="0">
  <HolidayRules>
    <HolidayRule>
      <Type>FLOAT</Type>
      <Month>May</Month>
      <Day>12</Day>
      <WeekDay>Thurday</WeekDay>
    </HolidayRule>
  </HolidayRules>
</Document>
```

Test in [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjib)

**Do note**: the empty rule for text nodes overrides the built-in rules, the `xsl:strip-space` is needed because `xsl:apply-templates` and `position()` semantic, the key is used for performance and convenience but it could be `../../../TableDef/ColLabel/D[position() = count(current()/preceding-sibling::D) + 1]`

Comment: last 3 lines in out put have to be like this:         </HolidayRule>  
    </HolidayRules>
</UploadDocument>  how to achieve it

Comment: I don't undertand your comment. Closing tag should match opening tag.